# Change message order in discuss odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I can't find where change message order in discuss module in odoo9

Where is location form and class from this image --> https://postimg.org/image/xffsxqqkf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `addons/mail/static/src/js/thread.js` line 59 inside the `init` function of the thread widget. The `display_order` is set as `ASC`. You only have 2 options there. For a specific order you have to extend this widget in order for you to define:

1) How will the order be determined,

2) When your order will be applied, on all the `o_mail_thread` widgets? Or just the discussion page?